# Integral equation which is equal to $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}{\frac{4 \sqrt{2}-8x^{3}-4\sqrt{2}x^4-8x^{5}}{1-x^{8}}} dx = \pi$$

I can use without a proof that $(y-1)(y^8-16)=(y^2-2)(y^2-2y+2)(y^5+y^4+2y^3-4)$

I guess that I could use the substitution: $x=\frac{y}{\sqrt2}$ and after it a partial fraction decomposition but as I have started to do it I have seen how can I continue it.

Comment: Yeah, I made there a mistake,thank you

Comment: This does not really qualify as an integral equation, or even as an equation. This is a proposition... It will be either true or false.

Comment: Exactly where are you encountering problems? If it is with the partial fractions part, it would be better to show what you obtained after using the substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using, as you did, $x=\frac y{\sqrt 2}$,$$I=\int{\frac{4 \sqrt{2}-8x^{3}-4\sqrt{2}x^4-8x^{5}}{1-x^{8}}} dx=\int \frac{-y^5-y^4-2 y^3+4}{1-\frac{y^8}{16}}\,dy$$
The roots of the numerator are
$(1,1\pm i,\pm i \sqrt 2)$ and among those of denominator are $(\pm \sqrt 2,\pm i\sqrt 2)$. So, a lot of simplifications can be done to arrive at
$$I=\int \frac{ 16(y-1)}{y^4-2 y^3+4 y-4}\,dy$$  Now
$$y^4-2 y^3+4 y-4=\left(y^2-2\right) \left(y^2-2 y+2\right)$$ Now partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{ 16(y-1)}{y^4-2 y^3+4 y-4}=\frac{4 y}{y^2-2}-\frac{4 (y-2)}{y^2-2 y+2}$$It does not look too hard now.